# How to: multiprocess with multiple iterations using only a few dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Ok, this is a bit difficult for me to explain but I'll try to be as clear as I can:

Let's say have a dictionary like the following (ignore the ridiculousness, used random name/food generators):

```
all_data = {"albina":"broth", "carlota":"vanilla", "masako":"garlic powder", "latoyia":"hamburger", "earl":"broccoli", "kristen":"raw sugar", "ione":"mustard", "chauncey":"rabbits", "jolie":"cantaloupes", "carina":"onion powder", "larae":"condensed milk",
"myriam":"asiago cheese", "christal":"coconut oil", "roselia":"black beans", "arletta":"red snapper", "marketta":"grapefruits", "sheryll":"navy beans", "scot":"arugula", "fernando":"chocolate", "bernice":"lamb", "libby":"cloves", "blanca":"cider",
"antonette":"sweet chili sauce", "dena":"chickpeas", "ja":"graham crackers", "kathe":"provolone", "jon":"lemons", "elicia":"feta cheese", "jeanette":"turkeys", "regan":"bok choy", "sabrina":"panko bread crumbs", "salvatore":"liver", "natalie":"breadfruit", "kathie":"chili powder", 
"lorretta":"cider vinegar", "colby":"date sugar", "shirly":"pistachios", "bret":"bouillon", "cira":"artichokes", "larry":"macaroni", "reena":"mesclun greens", "charla":"parsley", "lilla":"Kahlua", "erick":"cannellini beans", "esteban":"sushi", "na":"prosciutto", "wilhelmina":"pheasants", 
"dorinda":"scallops", "marvin":"salt", "madison":"dates"}
```

Then let's say I have a list of names of people of interest:

```
people_of_interest = ["albina", "earl", "elicia", "jeanette", "madison"]
```

Now let's say I want to calculate the frequency of the letters occurring with each person's favorite foods. Easy enough, we just write a few functions:

```
def food_associator(names_list):
    assoc_food = {}
    for name in names_list:
        assoc_food[name] = all_data[name]
    return assoc_food

def food_con_letters(data_dict):
    consus_fLetters = {}
    for name in data_dict:
        for food in data_dict[name]:
            for letter in food:
                if letter not in consus_fLetters:
                    consus_fLetters[letter] = 0
                if letter in consus_fLetters:
                    consus_fLetters[letter] += 1
    return consus_fLetters

food_interest = food_associator(people_of_interest)
food_con_int = food_con_letters(food_interest)

print(food_con_int)
```

{'b': 2, 'r': 3, 'o': 3, 't': 4, 'h': 2, 'c': 3, 'l': 1, 'i': 1, 'f': 1, 'e': 6, 'a': 2, ' ': 1, 's': 3, 'u': 1, 'k': 1, 'y': 1, 'd': 1}

Ok. Now let's say I want to compare the frequency of these letters to a randomly 5 chosen people. To do that I just run `random.sample` , easy enough. My random selections would also be stored in a dictionary with letters appearing called `random_select_dict` .

The problem I'm having is, let's say I want to do random sampling 100 times and then compare the average frequency of each letter to the `food_con_int` data. This would essentially compare the frequency of the letters of the favorite foods of the people of interest to what is the "normal distribution" of an equal number of randomly chosen people. And with each iteration, `random_select_dict` is remade and the frequency of letters is appended to a new dictionary which we will call `average_random` .

Now this probably isn't so bad with the dataset that I provide, but in my actual data I would like to do random sampling 10000 - 50000 times with many more dictionaries that contain large dictionaries within them. Is there any way I can implement multi-processing and using multiple cores for the iterative random selection, which is my current bottleneck? Is it even possible to open up a single dictionary and append to another single dictionary across processes without data corruption?

Alternatively, can someone describe a different approach I could use to multiprocess iterative random sampling data found in a dictionary. The data chosen by random selection undergoes multiple functions to process it before it gets finally appended to what is the `average_random` dictionary.

I hope this is clear!

Comment: 1.for one dataset, if it is too large, use `set.intersection` is better than a for loop. 2. for many dataset, you can use `Pool.map` and collect all the results from sub processes. You don't need to distribute many dicts at the same time.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Big yikes. I just updated it. Thanks. It should be working now.